# How to redirect on another page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I Don't have any ideas to how  redirect my page on another page after submitting my contact form.

```
my code is here 


<?
  header('Location: http://astrologerdelhi.co.in/?page_id=119, true, 301');

?>
but it is not working ?.

Thanks for your help
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `wp_redirect()`

```
wp_redirect( 'Location: http://astrologerdelhi.co.in/?page_id=119', 301 ); 
exit;
```

wp_redirect() does not exit automatically and should almost always be followed by exit.

[for more info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)